# Session Timeout Oracle ATG Jboss EAP 7.0

Tags: jboss7.x, atg

I am facing session timeout issue with Oracle ATG (Version 11.3) application running in JBoss EAP 7.0

When I checked the JBoss Management Console, I can see No of sessions reflects correctly before/after session timeout but not in the ATG side (I have checked the No of sessions from ATG component in dyn/admin)

So I Implemented Custom Http Listener and found that Listener receives the Session Created and Destroyed appropriately even though ATG holds the session indefinitely.

ATG out of the box implements HttpSessionBindingListener and add/removes the session and its details upon valueBound and valueUnbound events and I have checked that these components receive the event appropriately except unbound and bound event source is different. Since both bound and unbound source different code isn't recognizing the unbound event and hence unable to remove the session.

Bound Source Event:-
javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingEvent[source=io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl@efcf8fb8]

UnBound Source Event:-
javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingEvent[source=org.wildfly.clustering.web.session.ImmutableHttpSessionAdapter@5986130b]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a session leak on ATG 11.3 running on JBOSS EAP 7.0.  There is a patch 27507725.  which can be downloaded which addresses this (You will have to request access to this patch from Oracle)

Comment: Thanks bated, Appreciate your help